# How to use the zillow api with ZillowR

Tags: r, api, zillow

I want to access the `GetDeepSearchResults` info from the Zillow API.

**My code:**

```
library(ZillowR)
zapi_key = getOption('Myapikey')
GetDeepSearchResults(
    address = '600 S. Quail Ct.',
    zipcode = '67114',
    rentzestimate = FALSE,
    api_key = zapi_key
)
```

**Error:**

```
Error in GetDeepSearchResults(address = "600 S. Quail Ct.", zipcode = "67114",  : 
  unused arguments (zipcode = "67114", api_key = zapi_key)
```

Why does this error occur? What can I do to fix this?

---

**Edit:** I changed the code according to the comments and got this:

**My code:**

```
library(ZillowR)
zapi_key = getOption('myapikey')
GetDeepSearchResults(
    address = '600 S. Quail Ct.',
    citystatezip = '67114',
    rentzestimate = FALSE,
    zws_id = 'myapikey',
    url = "http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm"
)
```

**Output:**

```
$request
$request$address
NULL

$request$citystatezip
NULL

$message
$message$text
[1] "Error: invalid or missing ZWSID parameter"

$message$code
[1] "2"

$response
NULL
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ZillowR/versions/0.1.0/topics/GetDeepSearchResults) `GetDeepSearchResults` accepts only the following arguments: `address`, `citystatezip`, `rentzestimate`, `zws_id` and `url`

Comment: Hi Markus, I changed my code but I still get an error:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unused arguments error is typical when you pass arguments, which are not parts of the function. So R doesn't know what to do with those and returns the error. You can check the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ZillowR/ZillowR.pdf) of the function with `?GetDeepSearchResults`

This shows you the usage:

> ```
> GetDeepSearchResults(address = NULL, citystatezip = NULL,
>   rentzestimate = FALSE, zws_id = getOption("ZillowR-zws_id"),
>   url = "http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm")
> ```

To have this work, you have to set your id first with (you can create an id on https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/APIOverview.htm):

```
set_zillow_web_service_id("youractualkey")
```

So you function does not have the argument `zipcode` and `api_key`. Let's change your arguments to some which exist:

```
    GetDeepSearchResults(address='600 S. Quail Ct.', citystatezip ='67114',
                         rentzestimate=FALSE)
```

You surely recognized I did not use your `api_key`. This is because the default:`zws_id = getOption("ZillowR-zws_id")` calls your global `'ZillowR-zws_id'` which you just set with the `set_zillow_web_service_id()` command. So it's not necessary to change the default value. But you can skip this when you use `zws_id ="youractualkey"` from zillow

I made a random account I set up for validating. This gives me the output:

```
$request
$request$address
NULL

$request$citystatezip
NULL


$message
$message$text
[1] "Error: this account is not authorized to execute this API call"

$message$code
[1] "6"


$response
NULL
```

So I could successfully contact the server and my key was recognized. The account authority is not R related and has to be set on the website.

Comment: Hi @mischva11 I was able to get the output with your above suggestion and the format of the output is:
   <lotSizeSqFt>33024</lotSizeSqFt>
   <finishedSqFt>1726</finishedSqFt>
   <bathrooms>3.0</bathrooms>
   <bedrooms>4</bedrooms> . However, I want to write.csv this. when I do the same the error i get is Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘c("XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"’ to a data.frame
In addition: There were 33 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Comment: @bababoo i can't reproduce this, since i can't load data at the moment. I can't change my authoritys, the website is down. Try `data.frame(unlist(data))`. (data is your object) Your error message is pretty clear, you have something, which can't be transformed to a dataframe. In most cases you can extract the values with something like `data$xxx` or data[[1]]. Try to extract your data from the class and then save it as dataframe